# Выбор элемента из меню Option не кликается

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Есть список реализован через Option:

```
<ul class="MuiList-root MuiMenu-list MuiList-padding" role="listbox" 
tabindex="0">
<option disabled="" aria-selected="true" role="option" data- 
value="">Select Type</option>
<option role="option" data-value="PSU">Power Supply Unit</option>
<option role="option" data-value="RADIO">Signal Booster</option>
<option role="option" data-value="SWITCH">Network Switch</option>
<option role="option" data-value="GENDEV">Generic device</option>
</ul>
```

Далее есть: первая часть выбирает дропдаун меню, вторая часть выбирает элемент

```
self.dropdownSelectType = PageObject(self.driver, '//* 
[@id="app"]/div/main/div/section/form/div[3]/div')
self.selectTypeElement = PageObject(self.driver, '//*[@id="menu- 
type"]/div[3]/ul/option[2]')
```

соответственно производятся клики по этим элементам:

```
mainPageObject.dropdownSelectType.click()
mainPageObject.selectTypeElement.click()
```

В тесте первая часть `dropdownSelectType` работает и меню раскрывается, но элемент не выбирается и не кликается. Даже на сайте он не выбирается мышкой (не подсвечивается) НО выбирается.

Я пробовал много вариантов с xPath:

```
//*[text()="Power Supply Unit"]
//*[data-value()="PSU"]
```

но ничего не получается, подскажите, в чём причина?

Comment: тег `option` должен находиться внутри тега `select`... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

Comment: Как я понимаю, дизайнер фронт-энд реализовал это через Material UI, в этом случае Select нету...

Comment: по стандарту он должен быть, пихать `option` в `ul` вообще мощно, впервые такое вижу)

Comment: и в `selenium` для `select` есть специальный класс `Select` для работы с ними https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32382415/selenium-python-select

Comment: Я отправил замечание, вы правы. Вопрос тогда такой, а как по другому можно сэмитировать кликабельность выбора меню. Ведь физически я мышкой могу его тыкнуть и он выберется. Просто интересно, почему он по другим xpath ам не кликается, как например по "data-value" или как текст...

Comment: написал выше, будет работать когда `select` в верстку добавите